# mongo shell same command across multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am trying to do the following date conversion on multiple collections:

```
db.u201409.find().snapshot().forEach(
  function (e) {
    e.sta = new Date(e.start);
    e.sto = new Date(e.stop);
    db.u201409.save(e);
  }
)
```

As it can be seen, this is only for one collection, namely "u201409". The format is `uYYYYMM`. I need to execute this exact same command for the collections from 201409 up until 201604, so for u201409, u201410, u201411, u201412, u201501, ..., u201604.

Is this possible using a shell script, and if so, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mongo Shell command language is JavaScript, so just write JavaScript:

```
var a = ["u201401", "u201402"...]
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    db[a[i]].find().snapshot().forEach(
        ...
    )
}
```